# What does the phrase "That's all there is to it" exactly mean? Please explain also grammar behind that

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Here is the quote from series "Sherlock" s04e01:

> — You say he filmed that video message before he died?
>
> — Yes.
>
> — You also say you know what he's going to do next. What does that mean?
>
> (Another person:)
>
> — Perhaps **that's all there is to it**. Perhaps he was just trying to
>   frighten you.

Does that generally mean "that's all/that's finished"?

If yes, then what is the purpose of the second part of this sentence ("there is to it")?

And maybe I misunderstand it completely. The subtitles didn't contain any punctuation marks, that's also confusing. Could you explain this phrase in pieces, please?

Thank you

Comment: I forgot to indicate that the last remark was uttered by a third person (who apparently made the assumption). (That's why I have made an edition) But there is no much significance I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"All that there is to it" means "All that goes into making it" - here in the sense of "all that it amounts to" or "all the substance in it".

So "That's all that there is to it" means "There is nothing else to it" or "there is no nothing further to be found in it". Here probably "There is no further explanation or significance to it".

The only other use of the idiom that I can think of is "There's nothing to it", meaning that there is no significance, or substance, or difficulty, to whatever it is.

Comment: We'd usually use ***in***, but [(There's) some truth **to** what (he says)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="some+truth+to+what") is fairly common.

Comment: Would it be a mistake to say "That's all that is to it" (without "there")?

Comment: Yes, that would sound strange and non-idiomatic, @Cocoruzzy

Comment: Thanks, it became clearer thanks to you. I have one more question. In the sentence "All that there is to it", is "that" a conjunction (not a pronoun)? And in the phrase "That's all there is to it"  I guess "that" is pronoun, isn't it? It is confusing a bit. I.e., in these two sentences the word "that" is not the same and does not flow from one to another, am I right?

Comment: @Cocoruzzy: That's right. "That" is a subordinator in ".. all that there is to it", and may be omitted. "That" is a pronoun in "That's all there is to it".

Comment: It seems to me that if the expression "there is to it" were not an idiom, then it would be incorrect to structure the sentence in such a way: "That's all that there is to it" from a grammatical point of view. Instead, "there" and "is" should have been swapped, so the variant "That's all that is there to it" would be grammatically right. Is my guess correct or mistaken? 
I doubted about this question (how it fits), but as the structure of the expression became clearer to me, this question has matured.

Comment: @Cocoruzzy: no. _There_ is not the deictic adverb (which can be stressed), but the semantically empty subject pronoun used in presentatives such as _there is_ and _there exists_.

Comment: I am very sorry for my questions, that they have been going on for so long, despite the fact that initially I said that I have only one more question, I apologize. Thank you very much for answering. But the sentence “that's all that there is to it” if it were not an idiom, then it would be ok, and it would be unnecessary to omit “there”? I just never met with similar sentences with the words "that" as a subordinate conj. and further "there is". For example: There was a storm last night. That's all that was last nignt. OR "That's all that there was last nignt."???

Comment: @Cocoruzzy: "That's all that was last night" is grammatical, but hard to find a meaning for. "That's all that was on the table" is fine, but when locating in time rather than place you need either a different verb ("That's all that happened last night") or the existential "That's all that there was last night".

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your answers.

Comment: But "That's all that there was on the table" would be fine either?

Comment: @Cocoruzzy. Yes. The structure is different, so in theory there is a slight difference in meaning, though I can't express it precisely. In "that's all that was on the table", "all" is the subject of the subordinate clause; in "that's all that there was on the table", "all" is the complement of the very "there was" in the subordinate clause.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot

Comment: Sorry - the word "very" crept in to my previous comment. Don't know what I was meaning. Delete it.

Answer (score 2):

"to" is highly idiomatic there, and means something like "in relation to".

"that's all there is to it" means that there's nothing else that can be added in relation to that (whatever "that" is). The speaker admits that that is all he/she knows about it.

The sentence can be interpreted as coming from "**there is nothing else** to be added to it". If there is nothing else, then "**that's all there is** (in relation) to it".

Answer (score 1):

When explaining a simple procedure, or telling a simple story, you can say "That's all there is to it" when you're done, which means, "We're done.  Wasn't that simple?"

Here it means, "Perhaps there's nothing more to the story (the story has ended).  Perhaps he's simply dead and there's nothing else going on."

Also see:

> "there's not much to it" = "it's pretty simple"
>
> "(there's) nothing to it" = "it's very simple"
>
> "there's a lot to it" = "it's complicated"
>
> "there's much more to it than that" = "it's more complicated than that"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why is "there's" in the second phrase bracketed?

Comment: You can say "there's nothing to it" or simply "nothing to it!"